# How to make jwt bearer token not required in .NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have a configuration of JWT Bearer authentication, but sometimes instead of using JWT token, I want to use an API KEY in the request header and check this key in a middleware.

But in that case, when I don't put the bearer token in the header, I always respond with an Unauthorized response code.

How can I disable the bearer token check?

My configuration:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        // options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret)),
            ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
            ValidAudiences = jwtSettings.Audiences,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
        };
     });
```

Comment: Hmm.. the "correct" method to define this would be in my opinion to define a new authentication scheme there in addition to JWT Bearer. Then you would add a forward default selector on your JWT Bearer scheme that changes the scheme for the request to your API key authentication scheme if the API key header etc. is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking in a middleware a more idiomatic way you can achieve this by using multipe [`AuthenticationSchemes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0). See the MSDN link for more details but at a very high level you can assign add multiple authentication schemes, each with a different scheme. You then refer to this scheme name when using the autorize attribute (e.g. `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api-Key-Scheme")]`).

```cs
services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddJwtBearer(options => { .. })
  .AddApiKey(options => { .. });  // custom code
```

The `.AddApiKey()` method above will require a custom `AuthenticationHandler<T>` implementation, an example of how to do that can be found here - https://josef.codes/asp-net-core-protect-your-api-with-api-keys/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your method to disable the authentication check.

Then, create an `ActionFilterAttribute` and apply it to the same method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class RequireYourKeyHeader : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("YourKey", out string headerValue))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("missing header value");
            }
            
            // TODO: check if value passed in the header is actually valid
        }
    }
}
```

Apply with `[RequireYourKeyHeader]`

Comment: But  I want to apply this API key checking to all of my methods, then i dont want to add this attribute :(

Comment: @KiênĐinh Apply the attribute on the controller. Or use a base class with the attribute and let each controller (where you want to have all methods executing the code) inherit from the base class